Will this OpenSSH config provide the best security
Setting up my OpenSSH server on a Windows 10 server to be exposed to the WAN. (Up until now it has just been used on the LAN).
What I am trying to achieve:
When connection is from the internet, only 1 specific user should be allowed (remoteuser). Users connecting from the internet should be allowed to do very little: Only forward TCP ports to some specific hosts (See my PermitOpen directive), no shell access, no SFTP, no any of the other features I have probably never heard of.
Then, I have used a Match block to match connections coming from my secure LAN's. For these, security should be more relaxed. Allow password authentication, allow more users (although sftpuser1 should be limited to just SFTP), etc.
Questions:
Will my Match blocks work as intended, are these a valid way of achieving my aims?
Also, are there any other features I don't know about which I should disable for internet clients (In addition to shell, SFTP, X11 Forwarding)?
Config so far:

Port 22
AddressFamily inet #IPv4 only 
ListenAddress 10.10.10.15 #Listen on servers LAN IP

Protocol 2
TCPKeepAlive yes

HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

RekeyLimit 1G

#SyslogFacility AUTH # LOCAL0 - Logs to %programdata%\ssh\logs, AUTH - Logs to event viewer
LogLevel DEBUG

LoginGraceTime 1m
StrictModes yes
MaxAuthTries 3
MaxStartups 3:50:10

# SET TO 0 ON WAN TO DISABLE ALL BUT TUNNELS. INCREASED FOR LAN CONNECTIONS

MaxSessions 0

PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no

AuthorizedKeysFile  __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/keys/%u/authorized_keys #Where to look for keys for each user.

AllowUsers remoteuser (Allow only one port forwarding user for access from WAN)

X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding yes
PermitOpen ws1.internal:80 ws2.internal:80 #Only allow forwards to certain hosts & ports.

Match Address 10.10.10.0/24, 10.10.20.0/24
    LoginGraceTime 1m
    MaxAuthTries 5
    MaxStartups 10
    MaxSessions 5
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    AllowUsers john sftpuser1

Match User sftpuser1
    ChrootDirectory E:\
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /%u

Clarification: My Aim - SSH server open to WAN and LAN. When a connection is from the WAN (I.E source IP is NOT one of my LAN's), only remoteuser is allowed to connect (AllowUsers remoteuser), and can ONLY USE TCP FORWARDING. When connection is from the LAN, users john and sftpuser1 are allowed to connect and they can use features such as shell access, SFTP, etc.
So basically trying to run a hardened WAN config with minimal features enabled and a more relaxed local-only config, without running two seperate instances of sshd.
Edit: Just found this resource which helps to some extent with the Match statements...

I am confused. It seems your intention is that you are opening up your server to the WAN but then restricting the connections to your LAN which of course cannot be reached from the WAN.

Some progress:
After some testing, I have had to:

Remove LoginGraceTime & MaxStartups directives from within Match blocks, as sshd.exe complains that these are not allowed within a Match block.
Add the line Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe in the global config to allow SFTP to function.

Apart from these points, the Match blocks do seem to work, and I have a server that is hardened for connections NOT from the local LAN, (I.E internet), only allowing TCP Forwarding, whilst being more permissive for clients on the LAN. (Allow password auth, allow shell & SFTP, etc).
I will note that I found that if the permissions are wrong on the key files for each user, their keys will be rejected with no obvious indication of the problem in logs etc. Since I have specified a different path for keys (not in users home directories), for each users folder, I set the owner to SYSTEM, and only SYSTEM and the user themselves have any permissions for their folder. This seemed to work.
